# Merge back to trunk and include modifications to externals

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

In my svn repository, I have a trunk that has a set of externals on it. I have made a branch that also has it's own set of externals corresponding to the trunk (copied everything to a new location and referenced it the same way as the trunk, just different url). Now I am trying to merge all of my changes back into the trunk, including the changes I have made to my externals. I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to perform a separate merge at the root of the externals.

So, if your main merge looks like this:

```
svn merge -r xx:yy /myWorkingCopy http://svn/myproject/myBranch
```

You'll also need to do

```
svn merge -r aa:bb /myWorkingCopy/externalsFolder http://svn2/coolExternalsProject/myBranch
```

Comment: I've looked around online and discovered that svn merging does not support/include externals. I guess I'll have to write a script to do what I want. Thanks!